# Jquery Show/Hide based on radiobuttonlist in Asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Can someone help with the JQuery syntax to perform an action when a radio button list option is selected? I have a radio button list with two options.  I would like to hide a div when one value is selected and display the div when the other value is selected.

This is working fine but when the value comes from code behind. Its remain the same or it does not work.

Here is my Asp.net page code.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>       
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Types of Loan: " />
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radLoan" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" ClientIDMode="Static">
                <asp:ListItem Value="Car">Car Loan</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="House">House Loan</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Others">Others</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div id="divOther">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Others: " />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtOthers" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the Jquery script...

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var radioChecked;
            $('#<%=radLoan.ClientID%>').change(function () {
                radioChecked = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val()
                if (radioChecked == "Others") {
                    $('#divOther').show();
                } else {
                    $('#divOther').hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

Is there any option to avoid to add click/change event in the backend?

```
 radLoan.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return radLoan_onClick(this)");
```

Output Image...
[image]

Comment: So what i understand is that when you select the radio button value on the browser the jquery works well and when you set it on code behind it doesn't show the corresponding div. Right??

Comment: @GaganDeep Yes, It is selected the RedioList Item "Others" but the div is not getting displayed. Is there any option that adds in Jquery itself....

Comment: so before binding the change event, you can check if any of the values is checked on page load, and if yes you may display the corresponding div using javascript.

Comment: @GaganDeep your answer is marked solved but still, there is some issue. I can't use this for more than one control even after changing the var value etc..

Answer (score 1):

Like this may be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var radioChecked;
        radioChecked = $("#<%=radLoan.ClientID%> input:checked").val();
        if (radioChecked == "Others") {
                $('#divOther').show();
            } else {
                $('#divOther').hide();
            }
        $('#<%=radLoan.ClientID%>').change(function () {
            radioChecked = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val()
            if (radioChecked == "Others") {
                $('#divOther').show();
            } else {
                $('#divOther').hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I know I made a mistake in question but  the code  radioChecked = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val() is conflicting to other redio button list...